# iPhone: Problem with setting custom cell's accesory

Tags: iphone, ios

I can not set the custom cells accessory view while the page loads for the first time, any ideas?

In DetailView customcell's class I have this:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if(self.selected)
       self.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
       self.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

And In tableview controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    

      DetailViewCell *cell = [DetailViewCell  cellForTableView:tableView];

      if(somelogichere){            
        [cell setSelected:YES];
      }
        return cell;
}
```

I debug and hit that line so logic is true, but in debug I also see that after it sets the accesory then again it calls twice the selected method, which overrrides the accessory to none in the else inthe second call. setSelected causes the selected method to be called twice and overrides the setting on the second call cause somehow on second call self.selected returns false;

**UPDATE: I solved the problem by creating a boolean cellSelected property in the custom cell class and changing and checking its status rather than setting and changing the selected property of the cell, this is also better cause I can support multi selection tableview's better in future.**

Comment: I guess the code works fine. The default value of bool is NO. So when view appears SELECTED is set to NO. And thus according to your condition there would be no accessory view at the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work the second time after the view has loaded?

It most probably has something to do with following line:

```
  if(somelogichere){            
    [cell setSelected:YES];
  }
```

What is `somelogichere` ?

Depending on `somelogichere` your `selected` property might not be true the first time you run your code:

```
if(self.selected)
   self.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
else
   self.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Make sure you set your cell's `selected` property in the beginning. Or change the code inside your `setSelected`.

HTH

Comment: I debug and hit that line so logic is true, but in debug I also see that after it sets the accesory then again it calls twice the selected method, which overrrides the accessory to none in the else inthe second call

Answer (score 0):

You try this code its help u

```
 - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    UIImage *selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list_BG.jpg"];
    UIImageView *iview=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:selectionBackground];

    self.selectedBackgroundView=iview;  
}
```

**OR**

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of **tableView**:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

Comment: tnx could you edit this code? and what it has to do with uiimages?

Comment: yes I add this code and its set background image of cellIndicator

Comment: it has nothing to do with background views, please delete this answer

Comment: i think u want to set accessory in cell